# illegal start of expression error

Tags: java, swing

I am generating a JTabbedFrame from other frame.

In original frame, user enters "User Id" and "Password" & by clicking on submit button JTabbedFrame is generated. My JTabbedFrame is getting compiled successfully but i am getting error in original frame as illegal start of expression in public void actionPerformed(Actionevent ae)

I have attached code of both frames.Please help...

Code for Original Frame

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
     JLabel l1,l2;
     JTextFiels t1,t2;
     JButton b;
     Login()
     {
         super("Login");
         Container c = this.getContentPane();

         setLayout(null);
         l1 = new JLabel("User Id"); 
         11.setBounds(20,45,100,30);
         c.add(l1);

         t1 = new JTextField();
         t1.setBounds(110,50,150,20);
         t1.addActionListener(this);
         c.add(t1);

         l2 = new JLabel("Password"); 
         l2.setBounds(20,95,100,30);
         c.add(l2);

         t2 = new JTextField();
         t2.setBounds(110,100,150,20);
         t2.addActionListener(this);
         c.add(t2);

         b = new JButton("Submit");
         b.setBounds(90,160,90,30);
         b.addActionListener(this);
         c.add(b);

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
         {
             String s1="admin",s2="bravo";
             String user = t1.getText();
             String pwd  = t2.getText();
             if(ae.getsource()==b)
             {
                 if(user.equals(s1)&&pwd.equals(s2))
                 {
                    Vehicle v=new Vehicle();
                    v.setSize(800,800);
                    v.setVisible(true);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    System.out.println("Enter data Proparly");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Plse Fillup All Field","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 }
             }
          } 
    }       
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        Login l = new Login();
        l.setSize(300,300);
        l.setVisible(true);
        l.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     }
}
```

Code for TabbedFrame

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Vehicle extends JFrame 
{
    Vehicle()
    {
        Container c  = getContentPane();
        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        jtp.addTab("Car", new Car());
        jtp.addTab("Country", new Country());
        c.add(jtp);
     }
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        Student s1=new Student();
        s1.setSize(800,800);
        s1.setVisible(true);
        s1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     }
}   
class Car extends JPanel
{
    Car()
    {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Volkswagen");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Honda");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("GM");
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
    }
}
class Country extends JPanel
{
    Country()
    {
        JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox ("Germany");
        JCheckBox c2 = new JCheckBox ("Japan");
        JCheckBox c3 = new JCheckBox ("USA");
        add(c1);
        add(c2);
        add(c3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Student` class and where you get exception in `actionPerformed` method?

Comment: Sorry that is not Student Class . That is Vehicle class only... i have edited that part. I am getting exception in line whose code is public void actionPerformed(Actionevent ae).

Comment: You have a lot of compilation errors in your `Login` class. Remove them with help of IDE and all will be work.

Answer (score 3):

You have a method within a method, that's not allowed. Pull out the `actionPerformed` out of the `Logon` method.

BTW, check your `Login` and `Logon` naming. If you intend `Logon` to be a constructor, it must have the same name as your class.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Pulling out actionPerformed from Logon method worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your class is class `Login`, but you constructor is called `Logon`. Also, you're trying to instantiate `Logon` when your class is `Login`. You have to decide which one you want.
2. Also, take `actionPerformed` out of your constructor.